# How to make rotation animation in threejs editor and publish it?

Tags: three.js, html5-canvas, prestashop-1.7

I have already made a rotation animation in threejs editor using this script:

```
function update( event ) {

    this.rotation.y += 0.01;

}
```

But when I publish, and upload the app.json file in my prestashop1.7.6 website, there is no rotation. I want the rotation to occur. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: Do you mind sharing your published app in this thread? I've just tested with a simple example and hosted the exported app on a local web server. Everything went fine.

Comment: You should read the ["Creating a Scene" introduction](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Creating-a-scene), it walks you through how to rotate a cube exactly the same way you're attempting.

Comment: Sorry for replying late. @Mugen87 is this what you wanted - http://104.248.167.155/module/bespokestudio/viewer?id_product=35#/

Comment: btw I want the shirt to rotate.